# Regex - Remove the final character

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex

[`(?:(?:zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|\[0-9‌​\])\s*){4,}`](https://regex101.com/r/2q11GM/1)

As you can see, it matches numbers with whitespace.

**Question**

How do I stop it from matching the final whitespace character?

For example:

```
1   2 3 4  5<whitespace>
```

should rather be:

```
1   2 3 4  5
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to include the next character. I want to remove inclusion of the last whitespace character.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/2q11GM/2, you need to repeat the number matching subpattern.

Comment: Just trim the matches after.

Comment: I can't trim after because I am passing the regex to a third party library

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew. That's perfect

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/FppCR5/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you wrote the regex, trailing whitespaces will always be a part of a match, and there is no way to get rid of them. You need to rewrite the pattern repeating the number matching part inside a group that you need to assign the limiting quantifier with the min value decremented.

Schematically, it looks like

```
<NUMPATTERN>(?:\s+<NUMPATTERN>){3,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2q11GM/3).

In PCRE and Ruby, you may repeat capture group patterns with `(?n)` syntax (to shorten the pattern):

```
(zero|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|[0-9])(?:\s+\g<1>){3,}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1VEjKq/1)

Comment: You should use `\s+` instead of `\s*`.